# Conditional expression in Karate tool

Tags: conditional-statements, karate

Does anyone know how to create a conditional expression to test following validation of a column in a csv file in Karate (Cucumber)?

Column C is mandatory (numeric) when Column A in ('A'|'B'|'C') and Column B in ('D'|'E'|'F')